# jQuery toggle video mute for single video

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/calebzahnd/pen/VvZZeJ)

The toggle works, but only for one single video (or lets say, it works for every video on the page, not for one specific video).

Can I somehow but the mute button and the video together in a wrapper to make the button only function inside this wrapper? I think `$this` would be the way to do it, but I'm not sure how to use it correctly here.

```js
$("video").prop('muted', true);

$("#mute-video").click(function() {
  if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
    $("video").prop('muted', false);
  } else {
    $("video").prop('muted', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="mute-video">Toggle Mute</button>

  <video controls class="my_video"> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="mute-video">Toggle Mute</button>

  <video controls class="my_video"> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="mute-video">Toggle Mute</button>

  <video controls class="my_video"> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the relevant video element against the mute button.
You can use `.next` on the `currentTarget`.
Also, `id` of DOM elements should be unique, so I have changed the `mute-video` button id to `class` -

```js
$("video").prop('muted', true);

$(".mute-video").click((e) => {
  const video = $(e.currentTarget).next('.my_video');
  const muted = video.prop('muted');
  video.prop('muted', !muted);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="mute-video">Toggle Mute</button>

  <video controls class="my_video">
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  </video>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="mute-video">Toggle Mute</button>

  <video controls class="my_video">
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  </video>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="mute-video">Toggle Mute</button>

  <video controls class="my_video">
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  </video>
</div>
```